# Should I accept a useful answer even though it doesn't answer the question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

I have [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835730/configuring-perltidy-to-handle-custom-keywords) to which I am beginning to suspect there is no answer.

(I have asked how to do something with a library that may not after all offer the requested capability, as suggested by the absence of proper answer. 66 views and 6 upvotes for the `perl` tag is plenty, and usualy enough to get an answer.)

On the other hand, someone has suggested a workaround, which I have upvoted because it does help. If it becomes clear that there is no *correct* answer addressing the question, should I accept the *useful* answer?

**Clarification**

In answer to some comments, I wanted to clarify that the answer does not *solve* the problem, it just makes the library usable *notwithstanding* the problem.

Comment: That's up to you.  It's not our decision to make.

Comment: @Servy, I could rephrase my question as "is the accepted answer meant to be a correct answer"?

Comment: It's whatever answer you want to accept.

Comment: You said : 'it does help'. Why isn't it correct then? if it is helpful, and it **solves** the problem, accept it.

Comment: Accept is for the answer that helped you the most. If there is one or more that helped you, then accept the one that helped you most. If there is none, then don't accept what didn't help you

Comment: Maybe it has merit as an "outside of the box" solution even if it doesn't directly answer the original question as posed.

Comment: I think up voting if is absolutely the right thing to do. You're obviously not satisfied with the solution, so I would not accept the answer.

Comment: Is it just me or is it ironic that an answer still has yet to be accepted in this post?

Answer (score 42):

Do you still need an answer to your question?

- If yes, then don't accept any answer, because you are still in need of new ones.
- If not, and the workaround in the answer posted is the reason why you don't need an answer anymore, than feel free to accept that answer. Even if it didn't exactly answer your question as written, it led to the resolution of your problem.

Comment: The clarity of the question also needs to be considered. The clearer the question the more likely there is to be a recognisable (acceptable or good) answer. If the question is less clear then that is no reason not to accept an answer, as long as it provided useful information.

Answer (score 16):

At first it was quite strange to wrap my head around this concept. I know that most of the people, still til this day believe that the accepted answer is somehow an indicator of the best answer.

It's weird but true that in most cases the asker has the **least idea** of what the best/proper answer to his question is...

I have seen questions like:

*How do I find the last row used in a column in Excel*

and **accepted** answers like:

*Hey, don't bother with Excel, try VB.NET it's better than VBA in Excel a 100 times ..*

I mean come on!!! You feel free to accept **what has helped you**. The green check mark is not the indicator of what the best answer is. It only tells the system you've been helped and saves some people time by skipping your question.

The best answer, *at least in theory*, should be community chosen - via the voting system.

So, if your problem is solved and you're happy with a workaround provided in an answer - go ahead and accept it. The question is still there and it's not going anywhere unless it's off-topic. At anytime in the future, someone else may come in and provide a better (more suitable answer) which you will mark as the accepted one.

If something has helped you you upvote. You have done the right thing. But if you still need an answer, you possibly need more attention - offer a bounty on your question, it will attract people and therefore a professional/s may indicate to you via the comments section that there simply isn't a better answer available.

Answer (score 15):

I agree that you shouldn't accept an inadequate answer, if it didn't fully solve your problem, but if you *have* solved it with help from another answer, then please post up Your solution as an answer and credit the other answers for helping you get there!

Answer (score 8):

Just up vote the answer. And wait. You really don’t know if days, weeks or months from now someone will come across the same question & either provide a better answer or better insight.

Answer (score 6):

If you are relatively sure there is no answer for the question as originally posed and the workaround answer is good, you could modify your question so that the answer matches, then accept it.

I.e. change the question from "how to do X with Y" to "how to accomplish Z given..."

That makes it more likely that it helps others in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Ask yourself this question:

Will the answer that *you* find ok be one that others users would probably feel ok with as an answer to the question if they were asking it and saw this already asked question.

If not, just upvote and don't accept.

Answer (score 4):

[*me how*'s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256591/839601) makes an important distinction between two different answers: the **best** answer and the **accepted** answer.

Only the question-asker is guaranteed to know EXACTLY what the problem is, and he is the only one with the complete source of the original problem. He will presumably be the only one actually trying out the various answers offered.

And what's more, he came to Stack Overflow with a specific problem in mind. Between the time he posts his question and the time he accepts an answer, his problem exists. When his problem ceases to exists, presumably because of a posted answer, he should mark that answer as accepted.

The only exception might be when the problem was only able to be solved as an amalgamation of multiple answers, and what the community opinion of what best-practice might be in this scenario is probably best suited for its own meta question (which has probably already been asked).

And this answer that gets accepted?  The community may not even deem it the best answer.

---

*Q. I'm using <programming language A> and need to accomplish <task B>. I'm running into <problem C>. How can I fix this?*

*A1. If you use <programming language B> instead, it might be much easier to complete <task B>.*

*A2. Your error is in line 42. You need to change foo to bar.*

---

I would certainly hope the community upvotes and selects `A2` as the **best** answer, but if I asked the question and used `A1` as my solution, is it not right for me to mark `A1` as **accepted**?

The accepted answer can only be one thing: the answer that solved the problem that prompted me to post the question in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

> **Select the most helpful answer and change the selected answer if a better one arrives in the future.**

**Helpful** vs. **exact answers** sounds to me like **being pointed in the right direction** vs. **someone else doing the work for you**. We don't always get to find others ready to do the work for us.

**PS**: *I always select helpful answers in the lack of the 'perfect' one. I'm not lazy, I can take it from where the helpful answer left off.*