# An answer is accepted even though the OP explicitly states that it isn't what they want. Should it be unaccepted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58586636/3416774) received a comment from the OP:

> I have seen this example before but does not match what I need.

I understand accepting or not is up to the OP, but still, the green tick gives out bad information that **the answer works**. This is further affirmed in [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), although the whole paragraph seems to say otherwise:

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received **an answer that worked for them personally**. Not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they might not change the accepted answer even if a newer, better answer comes along later.

I know that if there are enough people to downvote it, it will sink down to the bottom. Yet, the fact that there is the green check indicating that it still works for them, which is clearly negated by their complaint. I also know that there would be a case where the acceptance refutes the claim in the comment, or the comment could be outdated and the they understood that it matches what they need. So if there is no evidence that OP prioritizes their acceptance over their complain, should we fix that bad information it it works? Maybe we shouldn't unaccepted it, but should we add a note saying it doesn't work? Not in the comment (the OP already does that), but next to the tick. Especially when there are others to confirm that it doesn't.

Related: *[Should I accept a useful answer even though it doesn't answer the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256479/3416774)*

Comment: Unaccepted by whom? Accepting or not is up to the OP. That's the end of it.

Comment: @yivi unaccepted by the community or mod. I understand the latter part. I just want to recheck why it shouldn't

Comment: It can't be "unaccepted by the community or mod". Again, only the OP can accept an answer or unaccept it.

Comment: The OP might have simply forgotten to delete their comment after realizing it did answer their question, no need to focus on it so much.

Comment: There is no idea to discuss. Again: **only the OP can do anything about it**, the community (mods included) can't do anything about it. Nor should they.

Comment: Also if you observe the times of the comments, accept and the revision history of the answer, the answer had one edit a day after the comment and some time after which OP accepted it, so that edit might be why the answer is accepted.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Should a SE dev unaccept the answer? Should moderators and/or the community have the ability to (un-)accept answers?

Comment: You can add a comment saying it's incorrect and explaining how, if you know such things. You can vote. Accepted answers are no longer pinned to the top. That's all there is to it. I really don't know what are you proposing, or if you are proposing anything. Are you?

Comment: Please have a look at [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer): "Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally." How could someone other than the OP determine what worked best for the OP?

Comment: @JeanneDark it seems that that article reaffirms my initial thought: "an answer that worked for them". If the OP explicitly says that it doesn't work, then all the reasons to have that check exists are collapsed

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that edit didn't significantly change the answer, and there was a recent comment reaffirmed that it still didn't work

Comment: No, not at all. The acceptance could also refute the claim in the comment. The comment could be outdated and they understood that it matches what they need etc. Again, it's up to the OP.

Comment: @JeanneDark I understand that it's also another way to interpret the contradiction. So if there is another person saying it still doesn't work, then can we conclude that the OP's comment is closer to what they meant than the acceptance?

Comment: Why not just ask the OP why they accepted the answer if it doesn't work?

Comment: That edit might not be significant but it introduced some new information (a "[clipboard extension](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-clipboard)") and that just might be something that does what the OP want. The comment you speak of is not by the OP so it is not relevant to the accepted answer. Also the accept was _after_ the comment (significantly so, plus after the aforesaid edit) so there is no need to discuss this...

Comment: @BSMP sometimes they don't comeback anymore

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat "the accept was after the comment so there is no need to discuss this..." -> that would be a valid point. But if it wasn't after the comment, would this discussion still valid? And how do you check the time?

Comment: The answer was [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8918721/stephan-t?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=6) after the comment was made by the OP and after the answerer left a comment in reply and edited their answer. So the comment was about an earlier version of the answer and seems to be outdated. And the OP is still visiting SO, so they could have unaccepted it in the two years since but chose to not do so.

Comment: @yivi " I really don't know what are you proposing, or if you are proposing anything. Are you?" Well, I just asking what we should do to the incorrect information that the answer works. If there are any proposal, it would be saying that the answer doesn't work, next to the tick, not in the comment

Comment: You already know what to do. If you find an answer that you think is wrong, use your votes. If you believe an answer could be fixed/improved, comment. That's all. Since you already know this, it's unclear what you are asking here. I'm sorry.

Comment: @JeanneDark I can't believe that how to find the answer. (Another side question: why does the acceptance activity not listed in the [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58557196/timeline)?) Also, assuming that the acceptance was earlier than the comment, what do you think?

Comment: @Ooker you can check the acceptance time by hovering on the green tick.

Comment: I think if and which answer to accept is solely up to the OP. The community can't do anything about it anyway, but it has other tools (voting, writing better answers etc.).

Comment: @yivi the problem is that even the answer has -100 vote, the presence of the tick still says that the answer works for the OP. If the OP says otherwise, and if there is no evidence that OP prioritizes their acceptance over their complain, should we fix the wrong information that the answer works for them?

Comment: *sometimes they don't comeback anymore* Sure, but sometimes they do and the OP is the only one who could do anything about it, whether that's clarifying that the acceptance is correct or unaccepting the answer. In this specific case the OP appears to still be active on the site, so I went ahead and asked.

Comment: At higher reputation levels, users can vote to delete answers with negative scores. I find it less likely that blatantly wrong answers will survive for that long. Which again, has nothing to do with the acceptance mark, which we can do nothing about.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat huh. I visit it in private mode with no extension and script running, but hovering it there is nothing

Comment: @yivi I think that's a good answer. Do you want to make it as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### No, it should not.

<sup>(And it's not an option anyway, even for mods)</sup>

You're putting too much value on the green checkmark, and misunderstanding its purpose.

> I understand accepting or not is up to the OP, but still, the green tick gives out bad information that the answer works.

That's not what the checkmark means.

The Help Center, at the beginning of your quote, *also* states:

> Accepting an answer is **not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly**. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for **them personally**.

The decision to accept is completely up to the question author, and isn't designed to be the end-all-be-all signal that this answer "works" for anyone *except* the OP.

This is confirmed by the help text that appears to the OP when they hover over the accept button:

[image: "Accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution"]That answer, despite the comment, was "*the most helpful in finding [their] solution*". End of story. Maybe it was the [answer author's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557196/group-nodes-together-in-cytoscape-js/58586636#comment103516461_58586636) that swayed OP over. Maybe it was [their edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58586636/revisions) the next day– who knows?

What matters here, with regards to the checkmark, is that the OP found the answer helpful, **that's it**. Via the answer's score (+3/-0 at time of writing), at least 3 others also agree that it's helpful. *You* don't have to agree, and can express that in whichever way you feel appropriate, but there's nothing wrong here, and no corrective action can or should be taken.

Comment: There's only one small issue. It seems that people are more likely to post an Answer on an unaccepted Question-thread. For this reason, if I want to know if there's a better solution than what I provided, I'll ask the Question author to un-accept my post.

Comment: @Scratte That's fine, but I feel that's still outside the scope of what the checkmark is supposed to mean. The discouragement definitely occurs, but I think that's a problem with _messaging_, not with the accept as a concept. Ideally, unpinning it will ease that pain over time, but we'll see whether that happens or not.

Comment: Good point about the bit "most helpful in finding your solution". If that's the case, should the help center article have that as well? Regarding @Scratte's point, I think if we reduce the impact of the checkmark to the OP only, then not only we should deprioritize it in ranking answers, but also not indicating whether a question is accepted or not in other places (e.g. the sidebar)?

Comment: "You're putting too much value on the green checkmark, and misunderstanding its purpose" - Well yes but actually also no. A green checkmark has a very specific meaning, the counterpart to the red cross. Right and wrong. And now here we have a green checkmark which does not imply that... it just irks me. In a world of a million icons, they just had to pick the one that is the easiest to misinterpret. All you have to do is mean well so you don't ignore signals thrown at you.

Comment: "*(And it's not an option anyway, even for mods)*" Well a mod could delete the answer and then undelete it. Deleting an answer un-accepts it automatically, IIRC. Normal users could also do this if the answer is negatively scored.

Answer (score 12):

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

If the OP wants to accept an answer, then they can accept an answer.  If people only look at the accepted answer as the authoritative answer, then there's little we can do to help them.

If you have a *better* answer, then you should post it.  Others that are around could agree with that sentiment and also upvote it, which would unrank the accepted answer (since it's not pinned anymore).

Comment: "since it's not pinned anymore" I'm so happy about that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, unfortunately

Comment: [Should I flag this as not an answer and subject to be deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers "Why and how are some answers deleted? - Help Center - Stack Overflow")

Comment: @Ooker No, you absolutely should not do that; because it _is_ an answer. See: [When is a 'Not an answer' answer not a 'Not an answer' answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309697/8967612)

Comment: @Ooker technically, it should be deleted, sadly we don't have the tooling to do so. On other sites, those answers get deleted whatever flag you use.